# How to display the tree structure from immutable map object using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I need to display the tree navigation on the page from json object 
(Json is the immutable map )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use one of this libraries:

- [react-treeview](https://github.com/chenglou/react-treeview)
- [react-treeview-component](https://github.com/yjcxy12/react-treeview-component)

Also you can check more examples of react trees on [this page](https://react.rocks/tag/TreeView).